# How do i call a message on the screen and delete a object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

In general, everything is very simple, I'm making a game about fishing, I have a script attached to a bobber that, when in contact with the river, `if (collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Conveyor>()!= null)` (Conveyor, because another object is floating on the river), stops the bobber `rb.isKinematic = true;`, starts the timer and when it expires, the function `Fish()` is called
The question is, how do I remove the bobber object inside this function, add the value of the variable `totalThrow` from another script, display a simple message on the screen like "You caught a fish"?
The whole code is here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollisionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;

    private float timer;

    private bool targetHit;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Conveyor>() != null)
        {
            rb.isKinematic = true;

            transform.SetParent(collision.transform);

            SetTime();
        }
    }

    void SetTime()
    {
        timer = 15;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (timer > 0)
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        else
        {
            timer = 0;
            Fish();
        }
    }

    void Fish();
    {

    }
}
```

And a script with a totalThrow variable:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Поплавок : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    public Transform cam;
    public Transform attackPoint;
    public GameObject objectToThrow;

    [Header("Settings")]
    public int totalThrows;
    public float throwCooldown;

    [Header("Throwing")]
    public KeyCode throwKey = KeyCode.Mouse0;
    public float throwForce;
    public float throwUpwardForce;

    bool readyToThrow;

    private void Start()
    {
        readyToThrow = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(throwKey) && readyToThrow && totalThrows > 0)
        {
            Throw();
        }
    }
    private void Throw()
    {
        readyToThrow = false;

        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(objectToThrow, attackPoint.position, cam.rotation);

        Rigidbody projectileRb = projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        Vector3 forceToAdd = cam.transform.forward * throwForce + transform.up * throwUpwardForce;

        projectileRb.AddForce(forceToAdd, ForceMode.Impulse);

        totalThrows--;

        Invoke(nameof(ResetThrow), throwCooldown);
    }

    private void ResetThrow()
    {
        readyToThrow = true;
    }
}
```

This script is simply to throw a bobber.

P.S.
I did a two timers, and attach a TMP to a script, so it looks like this:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (timer > 1)
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        else if (timer <= 1 && timer > 0)
        {
            timer = 0;
            Fish();
        }

        if (texttimer > 1)
            texttimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        else if (texttimer <= 1 && texttimer > 0)
        {
            texttimer = 0;
            _title.text = " ";
        }
    }

    void Fish()
    {
        texttimer = 5;
        _title.text = "You catch a fish!";
    }
}
```

But i don't understand a way to delete a clone of a bobber after timer goes to zero.

Comment: well in your code youve demonstrated you know how to get another component and use values from other componets.. so it depends by what you mean by "call a message"

Comment: you have to provide the other script that is responsible for displaying texts and the value of the variable totalThrow

Comment: i don't have a script that is responsible for displaying texts, but i attach script, that have a totalThow variable

Comment: also, i only want to show a text on a screen for a few seconds, no buttons or else, just a text